# how to add .html using .htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am converting my old site on wordpress and I don't want to loose any of the indexed "juice" as the old site has been going for 2years or so.So i have to make the same url.In my wordpress site i want to add .html at the and of my URL. I am using a plugin thats adding .html to all pages.
but its not adding .html on my product page.I want to add .html to all of my urls.

It has been suggested to us to use .htaccess rules to solve the problem, but we do not know where to start.

here is my wordpress site url.
http://www.fearfashion.com/

My full htaccess looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
 # END WordPress
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In the admin panel, under options, you can specify how a post URL and such looks. see: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/adding-html-to-end-of-url for example

Comment: i tried that but it won't work. i've made some changes in permalinks settings. like i add /%category%/%postname%.html in the Common Settings it works. But it applies to Posts, not Pages.So i used plugin called .html on pages it words for the static pages like contact and about us pages. So my question is How i can add .html in product pages too ..
i know we can do that using .htaccess file ..
but em new so need some help.Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can try a rule like this to force redirect non `.html` URLs to `.html`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L,R=301]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
 # END WordPress
```

Comment: thanks for your response. your code add .html in product pages but now em getting 404 page not found error.
can u help ? thanks in advance.

Comment: That means WP isn't recognizing product pages with `.html` extension.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response . so what exactly i need to do with my .htaccess file to get rid of this error.

Comment: See now .htaccess cant help further. We could add .html from rewrite rules that we did but WP needs to recognize these URLs. For that I think some tweak is required in your WP theme but I don't know WP code that well.